# Forcedeth - too many iterations (6) in > nv_nic_irq

Tags: linux, kernel, 64-bit, graphics-processing-unit

I'm having trouble with an onboard nvidia gigabit network, under times of heavy load on the network, I'm seeing this error logged:

"too many iterations (6) in > nv_nic_irq"

I'm running Hadoop DFS over these NICs and I see checksum errors build up until the whole thing just fails.

I'm running the 2.6.26-2-amd64 kernel, and my initial research seems to imply its a problem with the forcedeth driver.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is apparently quite common.   This question is several weeks old so you probably already found the answer, but if not the fix seems to be to add:

max_interrupt_work=*N*

to modprobe.conf, as in:

```
options forcedeth max_interrupt_work=15
```

Even with this change, I have still had some intermittent problems with forcedeth during large network transfers, but I never again received the error message you listed.